# Magento 2: Create different menus with links?

Tags: magento2, menu, custom-menu

Is there a way to create menus and specify which links go in each menu?

For example, I would like two menus in my header:
1. A specific list of items (just 6 items)
2. A few account page links (My Account) and static information pages (About Us etc)

I'd like to place the menus in two different positions in the header. Is there a way for me to create these menus and then use the XML layout file to call each of the menus and position them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but I created a UL in a static block and then displayed the static block via the layout.xml file in the position I want. I then styled the UL with CSS as usual.